# Constructing a DFA of strings that are in A but not in B

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

I am tasked with creating a DFA for the regular language L = A/B, which are the strings that are in A but not in B. The alphabet is Σ = {a,b,c}

I am not really sure where to even start with this one, so any hints or suggestions would be much appreciated. I have never really encountered anything like this before. How do I represent "not in B". I have only dealt with more 'tangible' things, such as divisible by 5, a*b(cb)*, etc. This doesn't really have a rule...I don't even know what the set B is.

Comment: Does it say that A and B are regular? If so, you know there are DFAs for each.

Comment: Remove all strings in $B$ (if any) from $A$. Now you have reduced to the problem of constructing a DFA for all strings in some set $C$ (where $C = A \setminus B$).

Comment: I am not sure if A and B are necessarily regular

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But how do i construct a DFA with things I don't know if they exist or not? For example if I know a string is abaaabac I can easily construct a DFA, but here I don't know what is in A or B, I can't just go if taking a goes to state q5 for example, because I don't know whats in the string?

Comment: Hint: The states of the DFA are the prefixes of strings in $A\setminus B$, together with a failure state.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I realise the approach I should take now! Thanks a lot :) Will give that a go now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a DFA $D_A$ for $A$ and a DFA $D_B$ for $B$.

Define a DFA $D$ for $A \setminus B$ as follows:

- The set of states of $D$ is the cartesian product of the set of states of $D_A$ with the set of states of $D_B$.
- The initial state of $D$ is $(a_0, b_0)$ where $a_0$ is the initial state of $D_A$ and $b_0$ is the initial state of $D_B$.
- A state $(a,b)$ of $D$ is an accepting state iff $a$ is an accepting state of $D_A$ and $b$ is *not* an accepting state of $D_B$.
- A state $(a,b)$ has a transition to state $(a',b')$ when character $c \in \Sigma$ is read, which I will denote by $(a,b) \xrightarrow{c} (a', b')$, if and only if $a \xrightarrow{c} a'$ in $D_A$ and $b \xrightarrow{c} b'$ in $D_B$.

Comment: On a tangential note, is $A$ \ $B$ standard terminology for strings in A, but not in B? Is this operator called difference?

Comment: A language is a set (of words) by definition. The $"\setminus"$ operator is the [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Definition_2), i.e., $A \setminus B$ is a set containing all elements in $A$ that are not in $B$. Since  the property of "being a language" is hereditary (a subset of a language is also a language), $A \setminus B$ will also be a language. So, yes, this is a standard notation.